# Can't combine two regex statements to work at once

Tags: regex, perl, filter

I have a simple perl code that displays the names of the files in a given directory

```
opendir my $dir, "./images/sampleImages" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @Images = grep {!/^\./} readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
```

I have added a regex statement to remove all single and double dots, since readdir adds them as special characters and this is working perfectly fine. However I want only the files with the extensions of .jpg/.jpeg/.png/.gif to be read. I have found a regex that does that, which is :

```
(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i)
```

But I can't seem to make them work together. I have tried everything I could find on the subject here, combining the statements in different ways but either they give errors, or flat out do not work the way it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip: `$` should be `\z` (unless you want to accept `foo.gif␊`)

Comment: Tip: `(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)` should be `(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png)`. You are capturing for nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work?

```
my @Images = grep { !/^\./ && /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i } readdir $dir;
```

Comment: It does, Thank you very much!

Comment: You could also go with `grep { /^[^.].*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/is }`, but I prefer pmqs's slightly slower, but more readable solution.

Comment: Agree @ikegami. This one is a trade-off between readability (and thus maintainabilty) and speed. When it comes to regular expressions  I tend to go with readability unless there is a very good reason not to.

Comment: It should be sufficient `my @Images = grep {  /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i } readdir $dir;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple match operators:

```
 my @dirs =
     grep { /\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)\z/i && ! /\A\./ }
     readdir $dir;
```

I typically make one `grep` per idea so I can disable them individually:

```
 my @dirs =
     grep { /\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)\z/i }
     grep { ! /\A\./ }
     readdir $dir;
```

And often I add in a `map` to make the full path since `readdir` doesn't do that for you  (and usually I do it wrong first then come back to do this):

```
 my @dirs =
     map  { catfile( $dir, $_ ) }
     grep { /\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)\z/ }
     grep { ! /\A\./ }
     readdir $dir;
```

And, `readdir` doesn't "add" `.` and `..`. Those are the virtual directories that mean the current directory and the parent directory. If those are the only things that you want to remove, then you can improve that part to match only those rather than all hidden files:

```
 my @dirs =
     map  { catfile( $dir, $_ ) }
     grep { /\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)\z/ }
     grep { ! /\A\.\.?\z/ }
     readdir $dir;
```

Again, even though I know that and written that a million times, I still only add it once I see `.` and `..` in the output. Some things never change.

Answer (score 0):

Following code filters in only images, no need to look at `.` and `..` at all

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $dirname = './images/sampleImages';

opendir my $dir, $dirname 
    or die "Cannot open directory: $dirname";

my @Images = grep { /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i } readdir $dir;

closedir $dir;

map{ say } @Images;
```